# Can I free mallocs that are being generated in every step of a recursion in C?

Tags: c, recursion, malloc, free

I am making a simulation with C (for perfomance) that (currently) uses recursion and mallocs (generated in every step of the recursion). The problem is that I am not being able to free the mallocs anywhere in the code, without having the wrong final output.
The code consist of two functions and the main function:

`evolution(double initial_energy)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

double * evolution(double initial_energy){
    
    double * energy_vec = malloc(sizeof(double)*50);
    for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++){

        energy_vec[i] = 0;

    }

    int i = 0;

    while(initial_energy > 1){

        initial_energy /= 2;
        energy_vec[i] = initial_energy;
        i++;
    }
    return energy_vec;
}
```

here is where mallocs are generated. Then I define `recursion(double initial_energy)` that return the total number of events, being events the times that the `initial_energy` is divided by 2 until its value is less than 1.

```
double recursion(double initial_energy){

    int event_counter = 0;
    int j = 0;
    double * Energy;

    Energy = evolution(initial_energy);

    while(Energy[j] > 0.0){

        event_counter++;
        event_counter += recursion(Energy[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return event_counter;
}
```

and finally the `main` function, that here doesn't make much a difference to have it, but for the sake of completeness here it is

```
int main(){

    int trials = 20000;
    int events;
    double initial_energy = 70;

    for(int i = 0; i <= trials; i++){

        events = recursion(initial_energy);
        printf("%i) events = %i\n",i, events);
        usleep(200);
    }
    return events;
}
```

So, is it possible for this code, to free the mallocs anywhere and have the correct result at the end? (The correct result should be 2**N - 1, where N is the number of times a value greater than 1 can result from dividing `initial_energy` by 2 successivelly. For example, for this code, the correct answer would be 127 at the end of the program). I have tried defining the malloc inside the for loop in the main function, and freeing it right after I call recursion, but it doesn't hold the correct result.

I only use C ocassionally (when python performance is too slow for some sort of calculations), so I do not have the technical understanding of the language that I would like. So I am open to whatever changes in the code are necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking, but `for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)` loops 51 times, and `malloc(sizeof(double)*50)` only allocates 50 elements.

Comment: Oh, thank you. Didn't realize that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're supposed to free memory right after the last time it will be used. In your program, after the `while` loop in `recursion`, `Energy` isn't used again, so you should free it right after that (i.e., right before `return event_counter;`).

Answer (score 0):

Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica is correct about the question you asked. But your code can be improved in a number of areas. If you want to see the final version, you should scroll all the way to the bottom of my answer for `run_simulation`, which is a dramatically better version of your `recursion` function.

Let's start with your initial function, `evolution`. If you want to allocate memory and initialize all bytes to 0, you should use the `calloc` function rather than `malloc`. Instead of

```c
double * energy_vec = malloc(sizeof(double)*50);
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){ // your original i <= 50 was wrong
    energy_vec[i] = 0;
}
```

you should instead do

```c
double * energy_vec = calloc(50 * sizeof(double));
```

This is usually more efficient than `malloc` + manually setting everything to 0, and it's more readable.

Second, there is no reason for `recursion` to return a `double` except. The most logical thing for `recursion` to return would be an `unsigned int`, since it will always return a nonnegative integer. This is practically a drop-in replacement; just change the return type and the type of `event_counter` to `unsigned int`, and your code will work just fine without pointlessly returning a `double`. I will make this switch - for now.

Third, a `double` can be larger than `2^50`. In the event that this happens, your `energy` array isn't going to be big enough. This is a serious problem, but it could be averted by dynamically resizing the array. A higher-level high-performance language like Rust or C++ would provide you with resizable arrays as part of the standard library, but in C, you'd have to do it by hand.

Fourth, you in fact do not need dynamic memory allocation at all because your code can be done with mathematics. You can actually get away with not having loops at all! However, to avoid using "floating point black magic", I will use loops in my answer. We first define

```c
unsigned int count_divisions(double d) {
    unsigned int count;
    for (count = 0; d > 1.0; d /= 2, count++);
    return count;
}
```

Note that `count_divisions(d)` is exactly equal to the conceptual length of `evolution(d)`.

Now, we should note that the only properties we actually care about for our Doubles is there `count_divisions` value. It's the only thing we use. Thus, everywhere I see a `double`, I will replace it with its `count_divisions` value. The resulting code looks like this:

```c
unsigned int * evolution(unsigned int divisions){
    unsigned int * Energy = malloc(divisions * sizeof(*Energy));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < divisions; i++) {
        Energy[i] = divisions - i - 1;
    }
    return Energy;
}

unsigned int recursion(unsigned int divisions) {
    unsigned int* energy_vec = evolution(divisions);
    unsigned int count = divisions;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < divisions; j++) {
        count += recursion(energy_vec[j]);
    }
    free(energy_vec);
    return count;
}
```

Now, we're beginning to approach the answer. But notice that we actually already know what `energy_vec[j]` is for each `j`; it will be `divisions - j - 1`. So we can completely eliminate the `energy_vec` vector and get the following code:

```
unsigned int recursion(unsigned int divisions) {
    unsigned int* energy_vec = evolution(divisions);
    unsigned int count = divisions;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < divisions; j++) {
        count += recursion(divisions - j - 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

which we can trivially rewrite as

```
unsigned int recursion(unsigned int divisions) {
    unsigned int* energy_vec = evolution(divisions);
    unsigned int count = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < divisions; j++) {
        count += recursion(j);
    }
    return count + divisions;
}
```

Now, we must use a bit of cleverness to deduce a better recurrence relation for `recursion`. It turns out that it is possible to show that `recursion(0) = 0` and that `recursion(k + 1) = 2 * recursion(k) + 1`. This is because

```
recursion(k + 1) 
= recursion(0) + recursion(1) + ... + recursion(k) + k + 1
= (recursion(0) + recursion(1) + ... + recursion(k - 1) + k) + recursion(k) + 1
= recursion(k) + recursion(k) + 1
= 2 * recursion(k) + 1
```

Therefore, we can easily prove by induction that `recursion(k) = 2^k - 1`.

So in fact, you're taking in the value `initial_energy` and returning `2^(ceil(log(initial_energy))) - 1`.

A final solution could thus be

```c
double run_simulation(double initial_energy) {
    double power_of_two = 1;
    while (initial_energy > 1) {
        power_of_two *= 2;
        initial_energy /= 2;
    }
    return power_of_two - 1;
}
```

which replaces your original `recursion` function at much less cost.

Comment: Mark, thanks for taking the time! I agree with you, but the case I posted here was an oversimplified version of the original code! In this case, I know exactly the result the recursion should return, so there would not be any simulation at all. But, in the real problem, the initial energy is divided according a Beta distribution with parameters that depend on the energy values. In that case, the final result is random too, and it becomes a real simulation! Posting the original problem here would take so much effort to read it and answer it. Sorry for not clarifying it from beginning.

Comment: @IgnacioMartínGómezF. Ah, that makes a lot more sense. I feel a bit silly for having wasted the time working it out, but it was a fun exercise. I should have read the question a bit more carefully.

Comment: Oh, don’t be! It was my fault for not clarifying.